# Is there way in BigQuery to get regular time zone abbreviations like EDT or EST instead of UTC+-X

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get my timestamp displayed as *2022-10-28 00:00:26 EDT*

However, with my current code

```
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'America/Los_Angeles') AS timezoned
```

I receive *2022-10-28 00:00:26 UTC-7* as an output

Is there any way to make UTC-7 look like default time zone abbreviation like EDT or EST in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are more than [25 time zones](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/current-number-time-zones.html) (e.g. UTC+9 maps to JST, KST, TNK, ...), mapping a time zone is a not `many-to-one mapping`. Thus, I believe we need a predefined dictionary (or a map) to map the number to a predefined string.

One possible approach could be using an array to look for the string for the index.

#### BigQuery Scripting

```
DECLARE TZ_DICT ARRAY<STRING>;
SET TZ_DICT = ARRAY<STRING>[
    'NUT', 'HST', 'HDT', 'AKDT','PDT', 'CST', 'CDT', 'EDT', 'ART', 'WGST',
    'CVT', 'GMT', 'BST', 'CEST', 'MSK', 'GST', 'UZT', 'BST', 'WIB', 'CST',
    'JST', 'AEST', 'AEDT', 'ANAT'
];

WITH
time_zone_data AS (
    SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Z', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'Asia/Seoul') AS time_zone_str,
    UNION ALL SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Z', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'America/Los_Angeles') AS time_zone_str,
    UNION ALL SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Z', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'Pacific/Guam') AS time_zone_str,
    UNION ALL SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Z', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'America/Puerto_Rico') AS time_zone_str,
    UNION ALL SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Z', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'Africa/Bamako') AS time_zone_str,
    UNION ALL SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Z', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'Pacific/Niue') AS time_zone_str,
    UNION ALL SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Z', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'Pacific/Norfolk') AS time_zone_str,
),
time_zone_data_processed AS (
    SELECT
        time_zone_str,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(IF(time_zone_str = "UTC", "UTC+0", time_zone_str), 4) AS INT64) + 11 as time_zone_index,
    FROM time_zone_data
)
SELECT
    time_zone_str,
    time_zone_index,
    TZ_DICT[OFFSET(time_zone_index)] as time_zone_string,
FROM time_zone_data_processed
;
```

#### Results

[image]